M2.3.7 Checkout Error: Exception message: Failed address validation: "Parent Order Id" is required
While using Paypal Standard Checkout, I am able to process through all the steps, until the very last place order call, inwhich I get the error code;

Failed address validation:
"Parent Order Id" is required. Enter and try again.

The system.log gives;
[2024-07-22 19:30:34] main.CRITICAL: Exception message: Failed address validation:
"Parent Order Id" is required. Enter and try again.
Trace: <pre>#1 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submitQuote() called at [vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php:453]
#2 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement->submit() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#3 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#4 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#5 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Quote/Model/QuoteManagement/Interceptor.php:39]
#6 Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement\Interceptor->submit() called at [vendor/magento/module-paypal/Model/Express/Checkout.php:808]
#7 Magento\Paypal\Model\Express\Checkout->place() called at [vendor/magento/module-paypal/Controller/Express/AbstractExpress/PlaceOrder.php:99]
#8 Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\AbstractExpress\PlaceOrder->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php:108]
#9 Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#10 Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\PlaceOrder\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#11 Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\PlaceOrder\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#12 Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\PlaceOrder\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Paypal/Controller/Express/PlaceOrder/Interceptor.php:26]
#13 Magento\Paypal\Controller\Express\PlaceOrder\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:186]
#14 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->processRequest() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php:118]
#15 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:58]
#16 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:138]
#17 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php:99]
#18 Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#19 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]
#20 Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:135]
#21 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php:153]
#22 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins() called at [generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php:26]
#23 Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php:116]
#24 Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch() called at [vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php:261]
#25 Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run() called at [index.php:39]
</pre> [] []

Any idea what the issue regarding this 'Parent Order Id' is? I've done a fair share of goolging, and have not even found anything close. I've seen some similar issues regarding the PayPal checkout, which enlisted fixes to Enable Automatic Assignment to Customer Group or PayPal Express Checkout configured with option "Skip Order Review Step" to "No" however neither of those quick fixes helped any.
NOTE: I get this same error on all payment methods, such as just trying to use 'Purchase Order' as well.

The issue facing by you are already resolve into MAgento Version 2.4.2.
But as you are using the MAgento 2.3.7,
You can found the solution from here :
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/b90d17652f41e4bf2f5b495b6a3a38bf0c1bfced
The issue with solution confirm by magento team.

Yes the solution work for me into Magento 2.4.1.

Would I need to make all changes listed within the 4 commits? (20,000+ changed files) or would I just need to do the commits listed on the actual commit you linked above? I tried the latter, and the issue still persisted

There are not 20,000+ changes, Kindly check there are only few files.

will you please open this file
vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Address/Validator.php
try comment out this line
'parent_id' => 'Parent Order Id',

and then proceed with order.
trying to close it down
protected $required = [
       // 'parent_id' => 'Parent Order Id',
        'postcode' => 'Zip code',
        'lastname' => 'Last name',
        'street' => 'Street',
        'city' => 'City',
        'email' => 'Email',
        'country_id' => 'Country',
        'firstname' => 'First Name',
        'address_type' => 'Address Type',
    ];


Thank you! This did bypass the issue and allowed for the order to successfully post. Is there any type of functionality that I am losing by omitting the Parent Id in this situation?

Parent Id is a required field for a reason, you cannot just remove it and expect the backend to work properly. The parent_id column is a foreign key in customer_address_entity table to customer_entity table i.e it associates customer to it's address.

Yes definitly we can't remove it.
